apparmor blocking magnet links from firefox
In ubuntu 22.04, I can't open magnet links from Firefox but I can from Chrome.
journalctl shows apparmor is denying the operation.
Jul 08 22:40:36 fs01 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1720492836.013:2325): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:254" pid=1875401 comm="Renderer" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jul 08 22:40:47 fs01 audit[1875401]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:254" pid=1875401 comm="Renderer" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000

I thought it might be due to the snap installation of Firefox, so I tried installing it a different way:
sudo snap remove --purge firefox
sudo apt-get purge firefox
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install firefox

But, Firefox just re-appeared in snap list after this. It seems Ubuntu wants to use snap here.
So... what is the best way to fix this? I have no idea how to mess with apparmor.
For context, I am trying to run this application with magnet links:
cat /usr/share/applications/qbittorrent.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=qBittorrent
GenericName=BitTorrent client
Comment=Download and share files over BitTorrent
Exec=/bin/bash -c "export PATH=/path/to/Qt/6.7.0/gcc_64/bin:$PATH && export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/Qt/6.7.0/gcc_64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && /usr/local/bin/qbittorrent %U"
Icon=qbittorrent
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;P2P;Qt;
MimeType=application/x-bittorrent;x-scheme-handler/magnet;

xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/magnet
qbittorrent.desktop

I had to add paths to QT 6.7 to get it to work when launching this application from the show applications menu. But I don't think that is related to the magnet issue since I am getting the apparmor error.

I have written a howTo remove firefox snap which might help you to replace firefox snap with a deb based one.

The following will solve this issue: How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 or later versions?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
